# replace standard checkbox with a custom image

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am using the dijit/form/CheckBox to successfully allow a user to toggle the visability of a Variable.  I would like to replace the checkbox with a custom image, that would show a highlight if its checked.  Do I need to recreate the wheel to get this done, or can I amend what I have thus far?

The checkbox is created with:

```
function updateAerial_1977Visibility(checkbox) {
    // alert("working");
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        Aerial_1977.show();
    } else {
        Aerial_1977.hide();
    }
}
```

and the checkbox is displayed in the HTML with:

```
<input id="Checkbox3" name="mycheck" type="checkbox" 
       data-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox" value="agreed" 
       style="padding-right: 20px;" onclick="updateAerial_1977Visibility(this);" />
<label for="mycheck">77</label>
```

Comment: This answer got me close - using http://jsfiddle.net/hqZt6/1/  I was able to add a border to the css for the "checked" state.  However, but if I tried to switch the red colored block to a custom image, it did not seem to work.  Before I try and stumble through this for an answer, can you confirm that this approach would work?

Answer (score 0):

try adding a src="path/to/image" into the input

Comment: How would this differentiate between clicked and unclicked?

Comment: isnt OP hiding it when it is clicked?